# Grid of expandable posts, post contents in div below row

Tags: javascript, wordpress, accordion

So I can't find myself an answer or explanation for a problem / question I have.

What I want to achieve is pretty complicated. For illustrating, here's a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GXaeL/3/

Could someone explain me, is this even possible to show the content of first row posts in one div below them. Same thing for the second row of posts etc.

I myself have had in mind that:

1. To combine somehow Tabs and Accordions?
2. This is purely an CSS positioning problem?
3. This is far more complicated than just accordions and CSS?

Since now, I have a PHP code, that creates a grid of posts. .posts are floated left and the row cleared when it hits 3.

```
<div class="post">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
} else { ?>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fallback_image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
</a>
</div>
  <?php
     if($c == $bpr) :
  ?>
  <div class="clr"></div>

<?php
   $c = 0;
   endif;
?>

<?php
  $c++;
  endwhile;
?>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

May-be someone can push me to the right path on this?

Comment: " is this even possible to show the content of first row posts in one div below them" -- why in one div?  can that one div not contain a div for each item in that first row?

Comment: The one div thing came because i don't know how to position an accordion div between the rows, so I thought it's not possible. But you sound promising, is there a way position the content div of each post below the 4 post divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your preferred implementation would be, so I'll offer a couple options.

The first option is similar to you put together on jsFiddle, except I wrapped the "trigger" `<div>` tags in a `<div>` of their own and added a "content" `<div>` tag to the single "content" `<div>` tag that you were sliding down and up... easier explained in code:

```
    <div id="row1" class="item-info">
        <div class="item">item-1</div>      
        <div class="item">item-2</div>
        <div class="item">item-3</div>
        <div class="item">item-4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentRow1" class="item-info" style="display:none;">
        <div class="item-content">content div for item-1</div>      
        <div class="item-content">content div for item-2</div>
        <div class="item-content">content div for item-3</div>
        <div class="item-content">content div for item-4</div>
    </div>
```

For this solution, the jQuery code you were using wouldn't need to change.

The second option is a bit more complex, but it allows each answer to be displayed individually rather than having to be displayed with all the other answers in the row.

Admittedly, there may be a more elegant, or jQuery UI-focused solution, but that's fine... I'll learn from that, too.

For now, I'll offer [the details of Option 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/gwKq9/) on jsFiddle, which I forked from what you offered in your question.

Let me know if you have questions, and I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thanks. The second option is almost what i want to achieve, but I didn't explain the content row part throughly. Is it possible that each contentItem spans 100% the contentRow2 width? So each contentItem is 960px wide?

Comment: OK. I actually got this what i needed! Just removed the placeholders width and height and changed the .item-content width to fill the area! But there's one problem with this thing at the moment. When I have two rows (or multiple) of items and click an item on the second row to open, the first row accordions will not close. JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gwKq9/27/ .